# how to Convert label.text to linklabel

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink, label

I am fetching some filenames in a label text:

```
label1.Text += filename+ Environment.NewLine;
```

I want to convert these filenames to hyperlinks(so that when I click on that filename, file should open). Now how to provide linklabel properties to a label  ?

Comment: Is this in WinForms? ASP.NET? WPF?

Comment: yes it is a winform applications.

Comment: ye it is a winform in c#.net

Comment: Please check this MSDN article about a `Windows Forms LinkLabel Control`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188769.aspx

Comment: Check this http://www.dotnetperls.com/linklabel

Comment: Why the downvotes??? It was a question i had :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
label1.Text += "<a href="yourpath/"+ filename+ ">Click THIs</a>"+Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Dint work ! 
gives output like this:
<a href=C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample PicturesChrysanthemum.jpg>

Comment: `winforms` is not `java`, if you want much more control over than this, using `wpf` is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: (However to make it look better, you should try customizing your own list of links such as using a `Panel`). This code use website addresses instead of files. You can replace the link text with your `file name` and link url with your `file path`.

```
Dictionary<string, string> links = new Dictionary<string, string>();
links.Add("Google","http://www.google.com");
links.Add("StackOverflow", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
links.Add("CodeProject", "http://www.codeproject.com");
int i = 0;
linkLabel1.Text = "";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> link in links)
{
     linkLabel1.Text += link.Key + "\n\n";
     linkLabel1.Links.Add(new LinkLabel.Link(i, link.Key.Length, link.Value));
     i = linkLabel1.Text.Length;
}
//Adding this to your form constructor would be OK
linkLabel1.LinkBehaviour = LinkBehavior.HoverUnderline;    
linkLabel1.LinkClicked += (s,e) => {
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Link.LinkData.ToString());
};
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot use :
links.Add("Google","http://www.google.com");
as Filename is to be fetched by a query

Comment: @Sagarikachaturvedi BUT your question didn't show that, it's so much confusion for me. You should update the question showing how you get your `Filename`. **Anyway**, you can use my code to add any link **once** you have the `Link Text` and `Link URL` (including `FileName` and `File Path`)

Comment: Thanks for this snippet. Now I am taking the query results in a string array and using some parts of your code I am able to access the files .

Comment: @Sagarikachaturvedi if it helps, plz accept the answer, it's just a SO's guideline, the best answer should be accepted.

Comment: @Sagarikachaturvedi just click on the `V-shaped tick` under the number of vote holder.